# Reporting services error trying to access with my domain/user

Tags: reporting-services, reportserver

I'm trying to access to the report manager url from SSRS but an error appears.

Something like

> domain/user doesn't have enough privileges to do this action
>   (**rsAccessDenied**)

And Configuration Settings Tab is not visible for me. In my SSRS Configuration I let privileges for this `domain/user` so I don't know why this happen.

My SQL Server is SQL Server Enteprise Edition 2014

Thank you,

Comment: Could you let me more information please? If you are saying about Reporting Services Configuration Manager, I changed here my data.

Comment: Sorry, goto `http://server/Reports` and add the domain user there.

Comment: It doesn't work, when I go to my localhost/[my-instance] this error appear and I can't click in no one place to  add a domain an user

Comment: try to launch the url after restarting the browser as a administrator.

Comment: Perfect! I had to open the url as an administrator using Internet Explorer , then I can use Chrome wihtout any problem. Thanks everybody.